# What does JTA not mandating support nested transactions mean?

Tags: jta

I am unclear on the above statement and how it ties into the various propogation levels within JTA. When a method is annotated with a Transactional Attribute as "Requires_New, a new transaction is always started even when a transaction is already existing.  Is this not a nested transaction?  Also Spring supports the "Nested" as an additional transactional attribute (over JEE).

Can anyone please explain what this means?

Thanks

Sirish

Answer (score 0):

Many databases does not actually implement nested transactions but uses transaction savepoints instead, so when it appears like a nested transaction is started in the application, what really happens is just that a transaction savepoint is created in the database, and if something happens inside what appears to be a nested transaction in the application, the database just rolls back to the latest savepoint.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savepoint

I'm not sure if this is really related to subject, though ...